# return a datareader in c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm trying to program a method to return a SQLiteDataReader object but without any success.

Here's the method's source code:

In a class file (DBUtils.cs):

```
public static SQLiteDataReader getAction(string dbPath, byte actionLevel)
{
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
    SQLiteDataReader reader = null;

    m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;FailIfMissing=True");
    m_dbConnection.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Actions WHERE acLevel=" + actionLevel + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

    reader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    return reader;
}
```

In the MainWindow:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    const string dbPath = "../../TestDatabase.sqlite";

    SQLiteDataReader zReader = DBUtils.getAction(dbPath, 1);

    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(zReader["acText"]));

}
```

Now, when I run step by step I do see that data has been loaded from the database when I'm in the getAction() method but when it comes back to the message box I get an Illegal Exception because there's no current row in the DataReader.

Anybody have a clue about what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: The reader is just a pointer to your data. The problem is the SQLiteConnection goes out of scope. You might want to return a list of items instead of the reader

Comment: @StuartSmith but the reader has a reference to the command object, which has a reference to the connection, so it can't get GCd, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there are results before trying to fetch them. If you know for sure there is only one result, you can do

```
if(reader.Read())
{
  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(zReader["acText"]));
}
```

If you expect multiple rows, do something like

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    // Code to read rows here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to finish the reading process:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
      ...
      using( SQLiteDataReader zReader = DBUtils.getAction(dbPath, 1))
      {
        if( rdr.Read() )
        {
          var someString = rdr.GetString(0);
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataReader always requires an open connection to read data from the Database, and you have to use `Reader.Read` method to get values from them, So you need to do small changes in your method signature like this:

```
public static SQLiteDataReader getAction(string dbPath, byte actionLevel)
{
   SQLiteDataReader reader = null;

   SQLiteConnection  m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;FailIfMissing=True");

    m_dbConnection.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Actions WHERE acLevel=" + actionLevel + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
   SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection)   

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    return reader;  
}
```

And in the calling method these changes have to be applied:

```
SQLiteDataReader zReader = DBUtils.getAction(dbPath, 1);
while(zReader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(zReader["acText"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  Would have accepted twice answers if it was possible.